# EPiServer Relate+ and AD

Tags: active-directory, episerver-6-r2

I have configured the Multiplexer to use ActiveDirectory provider, and I have granted access to the groups (both in web.config and EPiServer on root level). But I can't log in either in Relate or in Edit/Admin mode. In the EventLog on the Domain Controller I can see that the user I tried to log in with have successfully logged on to the domain, but relate does not seems able to handle. If i write wrong username/password relate does give an error, but with correct credentials it says nothing. The same code (direct copy & paste, no modifications at all) works just fine on a CMS6R2 site.

Answer (score 1):

After some tedious work I was able to get to the bottom of the problem. Apparently when using MultiPlexer with relate, I had to put `privider1="ActiveDirectory(Role|Membership)Provider"` and `provider2="EPiServerCommon(Role|Membership)Provider"`, on all the places in web.config.